# How to get text from element without text of inner element

Tags: xpath

I have an element of a following structure:

```
<div class="priceClass">
 <nobr>10.99</nobr>
 <span class="priceClass">
   <nobr>14.99</nobr>
 </span>
</div>
```

When I try to get text of div element I am getting text from span block, but I need text from nobr block inside div (10.99). I use the following locator - `//div[@contains(@class, 'priceClass')]`, which gives me 14.99 as a result. Can I somehow exclude span from searching?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `//nobr`

Maybe `//div[contains(@class,'priceClass')]//*`
which I think would select only the first element inside the div.

Maybe `//div[contains(@class,'priceClass')]//nobr[1]`

Answer (score 0):

The following may or may not work with your actual html, but as far as your sample is concerned, either of these should work:

```
//div[contains(@class,'priceClass')]//nobr[not(parent::span)]
#selects the nobr element without a span parent
```

or

```
(//div[contains(@class,'priceClass')]//nobr)[1]
#simply selects the first of the two nobr elements
```